# How to find empty group/folder in Photoshop with javaScript?

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I'm writing a Photoshop script to do some process with several custom layer groups. There might have some empty groups that I need to ignore in my case.

So I'd like to use the script to find empty groups, how can I achieve that?

What I'm thinking is to get every layerSets and check it's length. If it's equal to 0 then is empty.  But "length" of layerSets seems not work for this.

So which property should I use? Or any better way for this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't try to find those with DOM, because it has a lot of limitations in terms of traversing layers...

In AM code I'd do something like this: because Groups are actually two separate entities, I'll just go through all layers and check when `layerSectionStart` and `layerSectionEnd` (type `7` and `13`) are following each other.

```
(function()
{
    var myLayers = getAll(),
        emptyGroups = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < myLayers.length; i++)
    {
        myLayers[i].isEmpty && emptyGroups += "name: " + myLayers[i].name + "; index: " + myLayers[i].index + "\n";
    }

    alert(emptyGroups == "" ? "No empty groups found" : emptyGroups);

    function getAll()
    {
        var lyrs = [],
            prevType = -1,
            thisType = -1;
        try
        {
            activeDocument.backgroundLayer;
            var layers = 0
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            var layers = 1;
        };
        while (true)
        {
            ref = new ActionReference();
            ref.putIndex(charIDToTypeID('Lyr '), layers);
            try
            {
                var desc = executeActionGet(ref);
            }
            catch (err)
            {
                break;
            }
            thisType = desc.getInteger(stringIDToTypeID("layerKind"));
            var lyr = {
                name: desc.getString(charIDToTypeID("Nm  ")),
                index: layers,
                type: thisType, //7 is start of the group. 13 is end of the group
                isEmpty: (thisType == 7 && prevType == 13) ? true : false,
            };
            prevType = thisType

            lyrs.push(lyr)
            layers++;
        }
        return lyrs
    }
})()
```

Result:

[image]